# SwiftUI - Can't find EnvironmentObject in UITests

Tags: swiftui, coded-ui-tests, xcode-ui-testing, ios14, environmentobject

I'm trying to use @EnvironmentObject in my UITests, but I get an error at runtime.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Person found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Person may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

#### Doesn't Work

The following code throws the error mentioned above when running the UITest.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct RootView: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppView()
                .environmentObject(Person())
        }
    }
}

class Person: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = "Lex"
}
```

**UITest**

```
import XCTest
import SwiftUI

class AppTests: BaseUITest {
    @EnvironmentObject var person: Person
    
    func testPerson() {
        assert(person.name == "Lex")
    }
}

// For your info.
class BaseUITest: XCTestCase {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app.launch()
    }
}
```

#### Current alternative: global variable

The following code works just fine.

```
import SwiftUI

var person = Person()

@main
struct RootView: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppView()
                .environmentObject(person)
        }
    }
}

import XCTest

class AppTests: BaseUITest {
    func testPerson() {
        assert(person.name == "Lex")
    }
}
```

#### My Goal

My goal is to step away from the usage of global variables, as those are a code smell. I'm trying to resolve my code smells.

The answer I'm looking for can be:

1. A solution to allow the usage of @EnvironmentObject in my UITests!
2. An explanation as to why this is not possible and/or an alternative solution to both global variables and @EnvironmentObject that works, looks clean and is not a different code smell.